# Infinite scroll: how large should content batches be?

Tags: android, tablet, infinite-scroll

I am designing an Android tablet app that will make use of infinite scroll. User's connection speed will vary, of course.  The content to be loaded is product search results.  The GUI is similar to Google Shopping.

I have been unable to find best practices around how much content to load in each batch.  I'm guessing this amount should be related to the desired max load time.

Has anyone done this before?  How did you determine how much content to load?

Comment: Matt is absolutely right. If your list items don't link anywhere and are just to browse, you probably want large batches (since someone will be scrolling every time). If it's something like G+, when people will be spending lots of time on each loaded item, and less time browsing the items, you may only want to load 10 or less. There is no answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to load as less content as you can in each batch(depending of course in your app needs), downloading data on demand is the best you can do. I did something similar and in my personal experience the best was to run a background thread(Extending AsyncTask) in order to avoid UI thread hanging. This is the best way to publish results to the UIThread  without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.